# Backbone.js Single Page Architecture

Tags: backbone.js

Simple questions, am I correct with this approach.

1. I have a page with left, centre and right areas (divs).
2. Each area has its own Backbone object, MVC/R
3. Each area has its default HTML via a default JQuery template.
4. Each Backbone object communicates Restfully to Asp.Net.MVC via JQuery.
5. Depending on the JSON payload back from its MVC Action(s) an area can switch its HTML via a JQuery template.
6. I got some code from the ‘net that does JavaScript EventAggregation communications between the Backbone objects in a similar way to Prism for WPF/Silverlight.

Do points 1 to 6 seem generally ok?

Could I use some sort of "pure" JavaScript eventing to replace point 6, if so how would I go about this?

As you can guess, I’m coming into this from a WPF/Silverlight background

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Your list is good, and is a similar to how a lot of people are building Backbone apps these days. I would recommend against using jQuery templates, though. They are not supported right now, as the jQuery UI team is working on a road map to completely re-write them in to the jQueryUI project.

As for native JavaScript events - no. Stick with an event aggregator implementation that you are comfortable with. There isn't anything native in JavaScript.

You might also find my Backbone.Marionette project to be helpful and familiar. http://github.com/derickbailey/backbone.marionette

I also come from a .NET background, building composite applications (mostly in WinForms, but a little WPF). I've taken all of the core patterns that I used in building Winforms/WPF apps and built them in to Marionette. It removes a lot of the boilerplate code that I would normally write, and borrows ideas from Prism and other composite application frameworks.

Comment: Thanks Derick, Backbone.js / JavaScript is difficult in its own right not having much experience of it. Then I got confussed with the page architecture, should I do this, should I do that etc.

Comment: Just had quick look at your backbone.marionette, seems interesting.